# Multiple CMD instances command passing

Tags: windows, cmd, robotics-studio

I'm using the Microsoft Robotics suit, to start an instance in DSS Command Prompt it targets the normal `SysWOW64\cmd.exe` with the parameters `/K filepath\env.cmd`

Then to start the service in the DSS Command Prompt it would be something like `dsshost32 /p:50000 /t:50001 "/m:filepath.manifest.xml"`

I'm trying to have it do both in one command, such as `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /K "filepath\env.cmd" & /K dsshost32 /p:50000 /t:50001 /m:"filepath\WebCam.manifest.xml"` I'm not too familiar with CMD to know if it's even possible, doing multiple commands will not work as its a different CMD instance I believe.

Thank you for your time and any incite.

Comment: I have it down to something like a copy and paste works fine. For example `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /K "filepath\env.cmd" [New line]
dsshost32 /p:50000 /t:50001 /m:"filepath\file.manifest.xml"
[New line]` Due to it executing one command at a time, I feel its something simple such as a pipe or phrasing the statement differently.

Answer (score 0):

I was miss placing the logic, `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /K "C:\Users\blkennedy\Documents\Man\env.cmd & dsshost32 /p:50000 /t:50001 /m:"C:\Users\blkennedy\Documents\Man\WebCam.manifest.xml"` works, sorry for a useless question.